# IBM Worklight 6.2 multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty

**Environment Details:**

IBM Worklight 6.2

Oracle java version "1.7.0_67"

Liberty 8.5.5.1

```
[err] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[err] SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/WorklightServer/workarea/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/69/data/cache/com.ibm.ws.app.manager_
gen_a7f562a4-562a-4d33-8c23-98b948303abb/.cache/WEB-INF/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[err] SLF4J: Found binding in [wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/myapp/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[err] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Read the link. [Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494420/class-path-contains-multiple-slf4j-bindings)

However in my case I haven't add the library.

To test the conflict I have removed worklight-jee-library.jar from the **usr\shared\resources\myapp** and it works fine.

But this is not the solution. Please suggest a way to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you include the worklight-jee-library.jar in your WAR and in the shared resources folder. So either remove it from your WAR or the shared resources folder. This is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Stop you Liberty Server, remove the workarea directory and restart the Liberty Server with the --clean option.
Liberty profile uses workarea as a cache and you can have conflicts if at one time a class was loaded that is not the same than the current one.
And it looks according the entry in the cache that the worklight-jee-library is included in a war file.
If it is the case you have to remove it from the war. The worklight-jee-library must be used as a shared library and must not be packaged in a war file.